# Google Data API authentication

Tags: python, django, google-api, gdata, gdata-api

I am trying to get my Django app (NOT using Google app engine) retrieve data from Google Contacts using Google Contacts Data API. Going through [authentication documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html) as well as [Data API Python client docs](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html)

First step (AuthSubRequest) which is getting the single-use token works fine. The next step(AuthSubSessionToken), which is upgrade single-use token to a session token. The python API call UpgradeToSessionToken() simply didn't work for me it gave me NonAuthSubToken exception:

```
gd_client = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService()
gd_client.auth_token = authsub_token
gd_client.UpgradeToSessionToken()
```

As an alternative I want to get it working by "manually" constructing the HTTP request:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken'
headers = {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Authorization': 'AuthSub token=' + authsub_token,
               'User-Agent': 'Python/2.6.1',
               'Host': 'https://www.google.com', 
               'Accept': 'text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           }
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

this gives me a different error:

HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop. The last 30x error message was: Moved Temporarily

What am I doing wrong here? I'd appreciate help/advice/suggestions with either of the methods I am trying to use: Python API call (UpgradeToSessionToken) or manually constructing HTTP request with urllib2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the 2.0 documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#auth_sub) there is a python example set...

> Running the sample code
>
> A full working sample client, containing all the sample code shown in this document, is available in the Python client library distribution, under the directory `samples/contacts/contacts_example.py`.
>
> The sample client performs several operations on contacts to demonstrate the use of the Contacts Data API.

Hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently. Mine got fixed by setting "secure" to "true".

```
  next = 'http://www.coolcalendarsite.com/welcome.pyc'
  scope = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/'
  secure = True
  session = True
  calendar_service = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarService()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four different ways to authenticate. Is it really that important for you to use AuthSub? If you can't get AuthSub to work, then consider the [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/auth.html#ClientLogin) approach. I had no trouble getting that to work.